# Firebase Security Rules: Allow Read + Write to everything except a single collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to restrict read access to a single collection, keys, in firestore to only authenticated users with certain uids. All other authenticated users can view any other collection/document in the database.

First try is this set

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{col}/{doc}/keys/{key} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == "A" ||
      request.auth.uid == "B" ||
      request.auth.uid == "C";
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && !("key" in resource.data);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately users get this error message when trying to create a new collection in /{col}/{doc} - i.e. a collection sibling to 'keys'

> io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

If this were Java I would just run an indexOf on the path, deny if it contained 'keys' and allow otherwise. However, according to Firebase Rules Reference, a Path object does not support indexOf.

Here is the code the results in the error. In this case, the "boxes", and "CFI" collections do not yet exist in FireStore, so they would normally be created when the code runs.

```java
final DocumentReference firstDocRef = firestore.document("test/laksdfjasdf/programCounters/hjg65ffgjj");   
CF cfNew = Utils.getCF();
firestore.runTransaction(transaction -> {            
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(firstDocRef);
    HashMap<String, Object> updatedMap = new HashMap<>();
    updatedMap.put("num", cfNew.getNum());
    transaction.update(firstDocRef, updatedMap);

    Box newBox = createNewBox(cfNew);
    final DocumentReference newBoxRef = firestore.collection(
            "test/laksdfjasdf/boxes")
            .document("" + newBox.getBoxNumber());
    transaction.set(newBoxRef, newBox);

    final DocumentReference newCFIRef = firestore.collection("test/laksdfjasdf/CFI")
            .document("" + cfNew.getCreated().hashCode());

    transaction.set(newCFIRef, cfNew);
    return newBox;
}).addOnSuccessListener(box -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS");
}).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "Failure");
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to also show the client code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Note: normally people @ mention the person giving a comment if you make a change they requested.  They will get a notification so they don't have to keep reloading the question to see if there was an update.

Comment: Which of your rules is supposed to allow read and write access to that transaction? As far as I can see, neither of them match `/{col}/{doc}/keys/{key}`, as they do not have a subcollection called keys.

Comment: @DougStevenson there's a problem with the !("key" in resource.data) part of the second rule that is disallowing the transaction. When I delete this portion the transaction succeeds. My question is: how can I modify the rule(s) for this transaction to succeed AND for read/write access to the keys collection to be limited to only a few UIDs?

Comment: By the way, the user is authenticated successfully w/firebase in a separate part of the app